# Error "cannot find /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a" when installing cmake

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, glibc

As apt-get cmake's version is old so I had to download and install a new version of cmake by myself.

I ran `make` after running the `./bootstrap` command, then it showed error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a.
```

However, I couldn't find any `libc_nonshared.a` on my server, seemed like it was a quite old library.

I tried multiple cmake versions (3.25.1, 3.28.4, 3.29.0...) and they all required that static lib.

Comment: packages.ubuntu.com tells me that file is in `libc6-dev`. Did you install that? Also, you can ask apt to install all the build dependencies of CMake by doing `apt build-dep cmake`

Comment: I still coulnd't find the lib file after intalling libc6-dev. Could you help check which directory the file is supposed to be in? Also it showed 'You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list' when I ran apt build-dep cmake, what deb-src should I put for cmake dependencies?

Comment: Your /etc/apt/sources.lst should have deb-src lines commented out. `dpkg -L libc6-dev` should show the contents of that package

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason `libc_nonshared.a` seems to be missing, try reinstalling
`libc` using:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libc6-dev
```

Comment: I have tried this command to reinstall the libc but it still couldn't find the libc_nonshared.a file. Seems like it was removed from the new version libc?

Comment: Can you check if the file exists under the path that the error message tells you? `/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a`

Comment: No, it didn't in the path. Otherwise, the message wouldn't show up. The thing was the file didn't exist in the libc6-dev I installed as well.